# What NLTK technique for making extracting terms for a tag cloud

Tags: nltk

I want to extract relevant terms from text and I want to choose the most relevant terms.

```
How to config nltk data -> how, to, config ignored
config mysql to scan -> config NOT ingored
Python NLTK usage -> usage ingored
new song by the band usage -> usage NOT ingored
NLTK Thinks that -> thinks ignored
critical thinking -> thinking NOT ignored
```

---

I can think only this crude method:

```
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize(input)
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

and to save only the nouns and verbs. But even if "think" and "thinking" are verbs, I want to retain only "thinking". Also "combined" over "combine". I also want to extract phrases if I could. Also terms like "free2play", "@pro_blogger" etc.

---

Please suggest a better scheme or how to actually make my scheme work.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is a better pos tagging. This is a well known problem with NLTK, the core pos tagger is not efficient for production use. May be you want to try out something else. Compare your results for pos tagging here - http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/ . This is most accurate POS tagger I have ever found (I know I will be proved wrong soon). Once you parse your data in this tagger, you will automatically realize what exactly you want.

I suggest you to focus on tagging properly.

Check POS Tagging Example : 
Tagging
critical/JJ
thinking/NN

Source : I am also struggling with NLTK pos tagger these days.:)